# How can we write multiple structures in a .DAT file using C language?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am trying to write multiple structures in a .DAT file. But after writing it, I am not getting correct values of struct 1, while struct 2 is not able to be find by read function.
Please let me know the solution.

```
static const char fileName[] = "file.dat";

struct abc
{
int variable;
}ptr1;
ptr1.variable = 5;

struct xyz
{
int variable;
}ptr2;
ptr2.variable = 6;

int write_file_testing()
{
FILE *outfile;
outfile = fopen(fileName, "a");
if (outfile == NULL) return -1;

fwrite(&ptr1, sizeof(struct abc), 1, outfile);
fwrite(&ptr2, sizeof(struct xyz), 1, outfile);

fclose(outfile);
return 0;
}

int read_file_testing()
{
FILE *infile;
infile = fopen(fileName, "r");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
    exit(1);
}

while (fread(&ptr1, sizeof(struct abc), 1, infile))
{
    printf("Variable = %d\n", ptr1.variable);
}
while (fread(&ptr2, sizeof(struct xyz), 1, infile))
{
    printf("Variable = %d\n", ptr2.variable);
}
fclose(infile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide real and complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you have shown is not valid C and will not compile.

Comment: You write one struct of each type. You just have to read one struct of each type. Said differently replace the `while` loops with simple `if` test, and stop processing at first failed read.

Comment: The structs are exactly the same, so why are you defining two different structs?

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care, but us humans do) 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines, be consistent.

Comment: regarding; `outfile = fopen(fileName, "a");
if (outfile == NULL) return -1;`  before calling `return`, you should inform the user of the problem and what the system thinks caused the problem.  Suggest inserting: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  which will properly output both your error message `fopen failed` and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: this kind of code: `struct abc
{
int variable;
}ptr1;
ptr1.variable = 5;`  does not compile!  the assignment needs to be inside some function.

Comment: regarding; `outfile = fopen(fileName, "a");`  why are you opening a new file for `append` rather than for `write`

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. is a minimal complete example
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the desired functionality
4. properly handles I/O errors
5. opens the file for output with the "w" mode rather than the "a" mode so starts with a clean file
6. eliminates the duplicate struct definition and usage
7. documents why each header file is included

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fclose(), fread(), fwrite(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


void write_file_testing( void );
void read_file_testing( void );


static const char fileName[] = "file.dat";

struct abc
{
    int variable;
};
struct abc ptr1[2];


int main( void )
{
    write_file_testing();
    read_file_testing();
}

void write_file_testing()
{
    FILE *outfile;
    outfile = fopen(fileName, "w");
    if (outfile == NULL)
    {
        perror( "fopen to write to file.dat failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    ptr1[0].variable = 5;
    ptr1[1].variable = 6;
    
    if( fwrite(&ptr1[0], sizeof(struct abc), 1, outfile) != 1)
    {
        perror( "fwrite for first instance of struct failed" );
        fclose( outfile );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    if( fwrite(&ptr1[1], sizeof(struct abc), 1, outfile) != 1 )
    {
        perror( "fwrite for second instance of struct failed" );
        fclose( outfile );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fclose(outfile);
}
    

void read_file_testing()
{
    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        perror( "fopen to read file.dat failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( fread(&ptr1[0], sizeof(struct abc), 1, infile) == 1 )
    {
        printf("Variable = %d\n", ptr1[0].variable);
    }
    
    if( fread(&ptr1[1], sizeof(struct abc), 1, infile) == 1 )
    {
        printf("Variable = %d\n", ptr1[1].variable);
    }
    
    fclose(infile);
}
```

a successful run of the program results in:

```
Variable = 5
Variable = 6
```